# How to handle actions and views names in my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, string, embedded-resource

I have an ASP.NET MVC applications and i don't want to explicitly write the actions or the views names like this :

return RedirectToAction("Index"); or
return View("Home");

what is the best practice for handling those strings?

I use Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET MVC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) and inside there are extension methods allowing you to write:

```
return RedirectToAction<HomeController>(x => x.About());
```

Another possibility is [T4 templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/06/17/a-new-and-improved-asp-net-mvc-t4-template.aspx).

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525986/does-asp-net-mvc-rc-has-a-strongly-typed-redirecttoaction-method-already, if you like this solution but dont want to use MVCContrib.

Answer (score 1):

Use [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC). It will allow you to kill all magic strings in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a static class like so:

```
public static class Routing {
  public static RouteValueDictionary Index {
    get {
      return new RouteValueDictionary {
        { "controller", "Default" },
        { "action", "Index" }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

so i can use it like this:

```
return RedirectToAction(Routing.Index);
```